# What correlation measure for Wikipedia translated pages vs number of in links?

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, correlation, wikipedia

I'm trying to find a correlation measure for the number of Wikipedia pages an entity (an article) has been translated to vs number of links that point to that page (both measures that can point to the popularity of a page). Is it possible to correlate them?

For instance I have

```
Work, links, wikipediaTranslatedPages
The name of the rose, 500, 53
```

Comment: yes, you can also use a scatter plot with the features "links" and "wikipediaTranslatedPages"

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot) you can find an introduction to scatter plot.

You can read the graph as a correlation. Follow the immage you can define what kind of correlation is there between the two variable (image [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation))

[image]

1. positive correlation (0.7 - 1): if one variable increases the other
   increases
2. negative correlatio (-0.7 - -1): if one variable
   increases, the other decreases

Of course, if you want the precise value of the correlation you have to use the specific calculation library, according to the language you are using.